# "Virtualhost" for Tomcat8

Tags: tomcat

I am used to administering Apache web servers and am getting stuck on something with Tomcat 8. I installed Guacamole on my computer, I copied the .war file to `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps` which automatically was unpacked, but I couldn't access it on port `:8080`. I saw the files in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/guacamole` so I copied those over to `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT` which worked. I can now see it on port `:8080`.

Next step was to troubleshoot why it wasn't working in its own directory, so I setup in the `/etc/tomcat8/server.xml` this section:

```
<Service name="Guacamole">
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
                </Realm>
                <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/guac" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                           prefix="guacamole_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                           pattern="%h %l %u %t %v &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
                </Host>
        </Engine>
</Service>
```

I have tried a dozen different ways of setting that up with different `appBase` directories and so on. When I start Tomcat, all seems well in the catalina.out file, but when I check the log file for this service I get:

```
192.168.1.228 - - [29/Nov/2016:11:48:30 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.228 - - [29/Nov/2016:11:48:41 -0700] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I tried both `http://192.168.1.25:8080/` and `http://192.168.1.25:8080/index.html`, which I can see in the `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/guacamole` directory, but no luck.

I tried to see if I could get more verbose info from Tomcat to see if I could get what it though the path should be to those files, but there doesn't seem to be an option on this page: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html to get this type of output:

```
192.168.1.228 - - [29/Nov/2016:11:48:30 -0700] "GET /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/guacamole/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.228 - - [29/Nov/2016:11:48:41 -0700] "GET /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/guacamole/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Any help is appreciated in helping me identify what I have done wrong with my first Java webapp project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there was a problem trying to specify the appBase, just leave it webapps, and to access it you have to do `http://ipaddress:8080/guacamole/`.

I modified the setup script and added a load of instructions to the end of the script to help setup Tomcat and Apache.

https://github.com/ajhalls/Server-Setup-Scripts/blob/master/Guacamole-Setup.sh